# Getting JDBCExceptionReporter SQL Error: -64, SQLState: 37000 error after upgrade to grails 1.3.1

Tags: java, grails, upgrade, backwards-compatibility

I upgraded my app to grails 1.3.1 (from 1.2.1). everything works fine expect
foo.refresh() which does fetch new foo from database. It errors with:

> util.JDBCExceptionReporter SQL Error: -64, SQLState: 37000
>   util.JDBCExceptionReporter not allowed in OUTER JOIN condition in statement

I guess this has to do something with fetching, because the property that causes the error has to fetch a lot of other domain stuff (probably with OUTER JOIN in sql-statement).

This worked before, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is discussed at [this place](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/JDBCExceptionReporter-SQL-Error-64-SQLState-37000-error-after-upgrade-to-grails-1-3-1-td2238782.html):

> This seems to be related to HSQLDB, since the error goes away, when 
>   using a local MySQL-DB! **...**
>   Workaround: 
>   install hsqldb-2.0.0.jar in grails-app/lib